# How to validate a list of records to have unique and all enum constants using Jakarta bean validation?

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

My goal is to validate a list of records `Part` using a custom Jakarta validator. Each record has an Enum constant `key` and for every Enum constant, exactly one record with this constant must be available in the list.

Some classes:

```java
public record CarConfig(@EnumComplete(CarPartKey.class) List<CarPart> parts) {}

public record CarPart(String name, CarPartKey key) {}

enum CarPartKey { ENGINE, MIRROR, TYRE }
```

Valid `CarConfig` must have three list items of `Part` instances with the three different Enum constants:

```java
CarConfig config = new CarConfig(List.of(
    new CarPart("Engine block", CarPartKey.ENGINE),
    new CarPart("Rear mirror", CarPartKey.MIRROR),
    new CarPart("Front-left tyre", CarPartKey.TYRE)
);
```

Now the difficulty here is, that there are a lot more config and part-key classes, e.g. `BikeConfig` class using `BikePartKey` constants. Creating individual Jakarta-based annotations/validators for every config is one solution. But is there also a way to implement a generic, reusable validator?

I've been experimenting a while in the following direction:

```
...
@Constraint(validatedBy = { CompleteEnumValidator.class })
public @interface EnumComplete { ... }


public CompleteEnumValidator<E extends Enum<E>> implements ConstraintValidator<EnumComplete, List<?>> {
    ...
}
```

However, this is not accepted by the annotation, because `validatedBy` expects a subclass of ConstraintValidator and my own addition of type parameters does not fulfill this requirement.

Suggestions and help are much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean [*Jakarta Bean Validation*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/)? If so, say so in your question and in your tags.